Verifying shim SBAT data failed, no boot possible - hardware issue to get into BIOS
Originally I have this problem Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation
My question is how to get into the bios, because my hardware (keyboard) seems to take time to accept any input.
My PC is not starting, but showing this message:
"Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation. Something has gone seriously wrong. SBAT self check failed: Security Policy Violation"
I have a dual boot system Win11 and Ubuntu 20.04
Last night windows forced an update, which I had no option to postpone or deny.
Now before GNU GRUB appears, where I can choose, which system to boot, the above message appears.
I can't go into BIOS, in fact my keyboard isn't even working at that time (it usually does a few seconds after GRUB appears)
What are any options to do anything? 
Hardware is HP Pavilion Tower pc.
It's hard to find out relevant information, but if any more info helps, I give my best to provide it.

This question is similar to: Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From HP on how to enter BIOS: Turn on the computer, and then immediately press the Esc key repeatedly until the Startup Menu opens. Press F10 to open the BIOS Setup Utility. https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/ish_3912651-2318005-16

I found out, that my keyboard was holding me back. It's a steelseries gaming keyboard and took apparently a longer time to "get started"
I replaced it with a standard keyboard and I got into BIOS instantly. (by pressing F10, as I had tried more than 10 times with the gaming keyboard.)
Maybe it has to do with LEDs or other hardware. I usually have like 2 seconds after getting into GRUB menu, where the LEDs are not working and no input can be taken.
